# How to manually assign topic names to topics generated in LDA

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling

Just a sample of topics created in LDA:

```
    (0, '0.068*"murder" + 0.043*"crime" + 0.021*"shooting"')
    (1, '0.091*"police" + 0.032*"investigation" + 0.026*"law"')
```

How to manually assign topic label to each topic, such as Topic 0 should be named as " Crime", Topic 1 as " police investigation".

And while testing for new article, the topic label should appear  corresponding to it's percentage showed in descending order?

Comment: What library are you using? How is the output being generated? Without context, it is difficult to understand the question.

Comment: For the command                                                                                                                
                                                                                  
        model.print_topics(num_topics=2)                                                                                        
        (0, '0.068*"murder" + 0.043*"crime" + 0.021*"shooting"')
        (1, '0.091*"police" + 0.032*"investigation" + 0.026*"law"')                                                  
I want to assign topic names manually instead of Topic '0' & topic '1'

Comment: Which library are you using? What is `model`?

Comment: Gensim LDA model

Comment: See, the topics are generated by the `gensim` library itself. You cannot force it to generate new topics of your own.

Comment: I dont want to change the topics generated, just want to change to 
        (0, '0.068*"murder" + 0.043*"crime" + 0.021*"shooting"') , the '0' value to some manually assigned name

Comment: If it is a list of tuples you can directly do `tuple[0][0]="Crime"` and `tuple[1][0]="police investigation"`

Comment: I was doing that but it gives error
        
a[0][0] = "Crime"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-200-9275bae1442f> in <module>()
----> 1 a[0][0] = " Crime"

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Try converting the tuple to list, then change the values and convert them back to tuples

Comment: I converted into List & changed the required names, but when I want to apply the model on a new article, how will that topic name be generated instead of topic number?

Comment: Yes, as I said you cannot feed back the new topics to the model. Instead maybe you can maintain a mapping in the form of a dictionary - `{0:"Crime", 1:"police investigation"}` And can crosscheck anytime

Comment: Just keep a separate map from topic number to your chosen names.

Answer (score 0):

print_topics returns topic id which you will have to map & maintain to English label outside the model.
[documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html)